# How to overwrite previous hover states with Drupal CSS Injector

Tags: html, css, drupal, responsive-design, drupal-7

I have 3 divs that have divs inside them so when you hover, the divs inside will open up. Naturally, this causes a problem in mobile since iOS handles hovers as clicks and can cause this snippet to be very buggy. I want to make it so these blocks are always opened in

```
@media screen only and (max-width:734px){
}
```

With that being said, here is the tricky part. The client has their site built on Drupal and I need to do this through the CSS injector, and by industry standards, would prefer to do so without "!important" tags.

To give you an idea of what I mean here is how it's set up:

HTML Structure

```
<div class="hover-this">
  <div class="static-banner">
    <div class="show-on hover">
       <h1></h1>
       <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hover-this:hover .show-on-hover{
max-height: 440px;
transition: max-height 2s;
-webkit-transition: max-height 2s;
}
```

So how do I go about overwriting the existing code in a **Drupal CSS Injector** without using "!important"?

I have tried using this snippet but to no luck...

```
 .hover-this:link .show-on-hover{
    max-height: 440px;
    transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    display:block;
    }

/*cancel previous hover state*/
    .hover-this:hover .show-on-hover{
    max-height: 440px;
    transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    display:block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parent of `.hover-this` to do that. For example:

```
<body>
  <div class="hover-this">
    <div class="static-banner">
      <div class="show-on hover">
       <h1></h1>
       <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body .hover-this:hover .show-on-hover{
 max-height: 440px;
 transition: max-height 2s;
 -webkit-transition: max-height 2s;
}
```

This example assumes that the parent of the div is the `body` tag, but you should use another tag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I resolved it by looking back a couple stylesheets, the previous developer had a max height set on the hover of the div, so I had to change that in my former one to make the div always expanded.